# Flutter image_picker crashes when opening camera

Tags: android, flutter, image, dart

I'm trying to use `image_picker` on Flutter and it works perfectly on Android emulator. But when I try to use it on my real device, it crashes when I clicking the button to open the camera without giving any error. How can I solve it? My phone is an Android (Xiaomi Mi 8).

My code:

```
 File? _image;
  final imagePicker = ImagePicker();

  Future getImage() async {
    final image = await imagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _image = File(image!.path);
    });
  }
```

---

```
ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: getImage,
                child: Text("Foto"),
              ),
```

---

```
Container(
      height: 300,
      width: 300,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.red,
      ),
      child: _image == null
          ? Text("No image selected")
          : CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: FileImage(_image!),
            )),
    ),
```

Comment: do you have proper permission? an error is there, in logcat tab, inspect it

Comment: did you give permission? provide error log in console

Answer (score 1):

You have to add permission for accessing images.
For IOS

```
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

For android

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Comment: OP is not yet tring to write/read external storage, but trying to access Camera. Would't be more accurate adding `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />`?